# AppCenter is working regularly with all other updates except 4:

Tags: updates

AppCenter is working regularly with all other updates except 4:

```
4 components with updates:
 • shim boot loader to chain-load signed boot loaders under Secure Boot Version: 15.4-0ubuntu9
• grub-common GRand Unified Bootloader (common files) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27ubuntu5.1.7.1
• grub-pc-bin GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS binaries) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27ubuntu5.1.7.1
• grub2-common GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2) Version: 2.02-2ubuntu8.23+elementary27~ubuntu5.1.7.1
```

On prompting the update button an empty cursor appears briefly indicating “loading cache” and then suddenly disappears with no effects.

Tried `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt upgrade`. The last command resulted in:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin
grub2-common shim shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

I am running:

- elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera (Built on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS)
- Linux 5.4.0-89-generic
- GTK 3.22.30
- MacBook A1181
- Dual-Core Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T8300 @ 2.40GHz
- Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics
- 2,0 GB memory

After trying to install the single packages one by one via Terminal it would appear that this involves the removal (temporary?) of an essential package (shim/shim-signed), and I suppose the system refuses to do so. Apparently a bug (?)

Comment: `sudo apt full-upgrade` will show and upgrade the packages tho I'm unsure if you should proceed because of `You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!' ?]`

Comment: Thanks Santiago, that is exactly why I stopped my updating attempts. I will reboot entirely the OS (it takes less time than messing-up AND rebooting :-) ). Thanks for your time.